# Screen size incorrect after UICollectionView rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in my view controller defined as follows:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
layout.minimumLineSpacing = Constants.minimumLineSpacing
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = Constants.minimumInteritemSpacing

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor
collectionView.contentInset = Constants.collectionViewContentInsets

collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

I set the cell size in `sizeForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewHorizontalInset = Constants.collectionViewInsets.left + Constants.collectionViewInsets.right

    let cellWidth = isPortrait
        ? (screenSize.width - collectionViewHorizontalInset - Constants.minimumInteritemSpacing) / 2.0
        : (screenSize.width - collectionViewHorizontalInset - Constants.minimumInteritemSpacing * 2.0) / 3.0

    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: Constants.cellHeight)
}
```

with sceenSize as follows:

```
private var screenSize: CGSize {
    view.bounds.size
}
```

The property `isPortrait` keeps track of the orientation, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
isPortrait = view.bounds.size.width < view.bounds.size.height
```

and in `viewWillTransition` I have the following:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    isPortrait = size.width < size.height
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

When I rotate the device it seems that it is getting the incorrect screen size and therefore calculating an incorrect width for the cells. e.g If I load the app in landscape there will be 3 cell per row which is correct. However if I then rotate to portrait and back to landscape there will be 4 cells per row which is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the correct screen size after the rotation?

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question with what worked for me:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate { _ in
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Seems that the key was to use `coordinator.animate`, that way the screen size would be correct when `sizeForItemAt` does its calculation.

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer if it solved your issue

Comment: Have to wait two days to mark my own answer

Comment: @Kex it's been a long two days!

Answer (score 1):

This helped me lot a earlier to solve your issue. Details are added in the comments.

```
class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
    
    /// The default implementation of this method returns false.
    /// Subclasses can override it and return an appropriate value
    /// based on whether changes in the bounds of the collection
    /// view require changes to the layout of cells and supplementary views.
    /// If the bounds of the collection view change and this method returns true,
    /// the collection view invalidates the layout by calling the invalidateLayout(with:) method.
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        
        return (self.collectionView?.bounds ?? newBounds) != newBounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same effect as me calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` manually in `viewWillTransition`?

Comment: No. You force the view to invalidate. However, my code just detects the layout changes itself. However, as you tried using `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`, I would suggest a `collectionView.reloadData()` after invalidating. This would help you here as far as I understand.

Comment: Tested it. I agree this is a better way to force the cells to invalidate, however the screen width for my cell width calculation is still wrong after the rotation is finished.